# How to add some constraints not to allow two way relationship in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby on rails to develop some system. In my system i have two models namely course and course_prerequisite. Course A could be prerequisite to course B but course B should never be prerequisite back to course A. how can i enforce this kind of relationship in my system?

Comment: Presumably it's more complicated than that - you want to forbid all loops (for example: to do A you need B, to do B you need C, to do C you need A), not just loops of two (A needs B, B needs A)?

Answer (score 0):

One way that I think of is through validations:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :course_prerequisites

 belongs_to :user

 validate :course_prerequisites

 private

 def course_prerequisites
   unless user.completed_all_prerequisites(course_prerequisites)
     errors.add_to_base("Must complete all prerequisites")
   end   
 end

end
```

Something like that. Note that adding an error programmatically might not invalidate your model. If that happens to you (try it out) either raise an exception or see if the model is valid before saving.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem Bill was asking about. Your code appears to be checking that a user has completed all the prerequisites for a course; Bill was asking how to check that there are no courses where you have to take A before B, but B before A (so you can never in fact complete either!).

Comment: Yes i am not asking to check for prerequisite course completion of a user but to check that if course A should be taken before course B, then the system should not accept the case that course B should be taken before course A. Can i do this by righting some constraint in the database? if yes how can i do that?

Comment: I am still waiting for some idea on how to do the above problem. Please i need help!!